# Pandas : create new columns based on column values and populate with data from other columns as key value pair

Tags: python, pandas

After getting the values from the K columns it leaves an empty cells.

I have a sample dataset here like

```
Id K1   V1    K2   V2     K3  V3...
1  COL1 TEST1 COL2 TEST2 COL3 TEST3
2  COL2 TEST4 COL1 TEST2 COL3 TEST4
3  COL4 TEST2 COL2 TEST1 COL1 TEST2
4  COL3 TEST5 COL2 TEST5 COL4 TEST1
```

..

I want to make it like:

```
Id  COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4...
1   TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 NULL
2   TEST2 TEST4 TEST4 NULL
3   TEST2 TEST1 NULL  TEST2
4   NULL  TEST5 TEST5 TEST1
```

..

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape with [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = (pd
   .wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['K', 'V'], i='Id', j='X')
   .droplevel(1)
   .pivot(columns='K', values='V')
   .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
   #.fillna('NULL') # optional
)
```

*NB. This is assuming that "Id" is a column.*

Output:

```
   Id   COL1   COL2   COL3   COL4
0   1  TEST1  TEST2  TEST3    NaN
1   2  TEST2  TEST4  TEST4    NaN
2   3  TEST2  TEST1    NaN  TEST2
3   4    NaN  TEST5  TEST5  TEST1
```